# SMTP Fully-qualified domain name configuration

Tags: configuration, smtp, dns, fqdn

I have trouble with receiving of email from from my SMTP to internal (the same domain) email.

I mean that when I sent email from my registration@example.com email to private email somename@yahoo.com this email was delivered. But when I sent from registration@example.com to info@example.com this email was not delivered.

Then I found that in my SMTP the parameter "Fully-qualified domain name" set to name of computer "COMPUTERNAME" but not real domain. When I changed FQDN from "COMPUTERNAME" to "example.com" it is not resolved the problem with info@example.com. But emails still successfully delivered to private emails like @yahoo.com.

When I changed FQDN from "example.com" to "www.example.com" the problem was resolved and emails are successfully delivered to my internal email info@example.com.

I need to know what is the difference between "example.com" and "www.example.com" FQDN-s and why it is not works in first case ("example.com")? Have you any ideas?

Thanks a lot!
Victor

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/599712/best-practices-for-fqdn-for-standalone-domain-is-a-two-part-domain-tld-okay/599725#599725

Answer (score 0):

see wikipedia
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_domain_name

but basically example.com *may* be the same as www.example.com as far as your DNS routing is set up, but *could* also point to ww1.example.com, api.example.com or boogiemonster.example.com. without the actual full hostname, the 'aaa' part of aaa.bbb.ccc, the reference is ambiguous and not fully qualified...